# Spring mvc @RequestBody how to parse JPA Entity with @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jpa, jackson

I have 2 Entities: User and UserAlias. User have composite PK. I have some questions:

1. How to parse JSON in spring MVC controller to populate User and UserPK objects, for example with this data:

   {
     "id" : 1,
     "name" : "newUser",
     "aliases": [
       "alias1",
       "alias2",
       "alias3"
     ]
   }

If i write`public void createUser(@RequestBody User user)` i will obviously get an exception.
**How can i write my controller method to parse data to both entities?**

2. For now i'm using a DTO object to parse JSON with @RequestBody and populate models. But i'm not sure this is good way to do this task.

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserPK userid;

    public User(){}
    public User(UserPK userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.aliases = aliases;
    }

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    public List<UserAlias> aliases = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

UserPK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class UserPK implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public UserPK(){};

    public UserPK(Integer id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

UserAlias.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_alias")
public class UserAlias {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_alias")
    private String userAlias;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(
                    referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    referencedColumnName = "name")
    })
    @JsonIgnore
    public User user;

    public UserAlias(){}
    public UserAlias(String userAlias) {
        this.userAlias = userAlias;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. First question:**

> How to parse JSON in spring MVC controller to populate User and UserPK objects?

Well your JSON have to be matching your entity structure, so you need to have a `UserId` object, inside your `User` object in order to match the expected structure. In your case the JSON you are sharing won't match that, and will throw an Exception when passed to the Spring Controller.

This is what you will need as JSON:

```
{ "userid": {"id" : 1, "name" : "newUser"}, "aliases": [ "alias1", "alias2", "alias3" ] }
```

**2. Second question:**

> For now i'm using a DTO object to parse JSON with @RequestBody and populate models. But i'm not sure this is good way to do this task?

Yes it's a good way to use `DTO` especially if you won't to keep the same `JSON` structure you are using right now, and using the passed `DTO` you can construct your `User` object respectively.

### Using [`@JsonUnwrapped` annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html):

If you want to avoid the use of a `DTO`, you can just use **[Jackson's `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html)**, with your `userId` field, this way its properties will be serialized as properties of the `User` class and your first `JSON` will be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how i should add `UserId` object to `User` class? I'm already have `@EmbeddedId private UserPK userid;` Maybe I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @insci Actually `userid` in the json, will be the representation of `@EmbeddedId private UserPK userid;`, it's the name `userId` that will indicate this and of course the same structure. You don't need to edit anything in your Entities.

Comment: Ok i got it, but is there way not modify the json? I mean for now i'm using DTO, but can there be any other ways to deal with this problem?

Comment: @insci Yes you can use `@JsonUnwrapped`Jackson annotation over your `userId` field, its properties will be serialized as properties of the `User` class and your first json will be matched.