# Composite PK object not being populated by controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working with Spring and Hibernate. I have a Student class with a composite primary key. To achieve this, I am using `@Embeddedable` and `@EmbeddedId`. However, in my controller, the values are not populating automatically and the value comes as `null`.

`Student.java`

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentId studentId;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class StudentId implements Serializable {
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }
}
```

`StudentController.java`

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {

    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public void setStudentService(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        System.out.println(student); // Prints Student(studentId=null)
        // this.studentService.addStudent(student);
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to automatically populate the values in the Student object.

**Note**: I agree a composite PK here doesn't really make sense. This is more of a practice project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208935/spring-mvc-requestbody-how-to-parse-jpa-entity-with-embeddedid).

The only change was adding the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation.

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @JsonUnwrapped // <= This piece
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentId studentId;

    private int age;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class StudentId implements Serializable {
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use Json wrapped annotation

```
  @JsonUnwrapped
  @EmbeddedId
  private StudentId studentId;
```